# Giswater plugin version 3.4

Tags: qgis

I am new to this. My [Giswater](https://github.com/Giswater/giswater_qgis_plugin) plugin icon does not function upon clicking. But successfully installed. I have installed postgresql, pgadmin 3, enabled spatial extensions postgis and pgrouting,

[image: my qgis with giswater plugin installed]

Answer (score 0):

Have you make sure of your postgis connection is correct and can connect to your database? If so, Giswater should open and show this connection.